# How can i create new AMI of window platform with 50 GB storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services

i want to launch AMI VM of 50GB storage. it was before 30GB ,i need to change it. how to do this ? 
    depending upon cpu and RAM size i  set  instance type
    like t2.medium, t2.large...

Comment: Please clarify your question: Are you simply wanting to launch a new Amazon EC2 instance, or are you wanting to create an AMI? Or are you wanting to modify the storage size of an existing instance?

Comment: @John Rotenstein i want ,modify the storage size of an existing instance.

Comment: Use the **Modify** command. See: [Modifying the Size, IOPS, or Type of an EBS Volume on Windows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ebs-modify-volume.html) and [Modifying the Size, IOPS, or Type of an EBS Volume on Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modify-volume.html)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify an existing AMI. If you have a running instance, modify its disk size, and create an AMI out of it. 
To edit the size of the disk of a running instance, locate its volume, right click on it and click Modify. Then change the Size and press Modify. Read more [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-ebs-root-volume-windows/). Note that after modifying the disk size on AWS Console, you need to RDP to your instance and extend the disk in disk management (refer to the step 7 in the linked page).